# Constructor and Method chaining with a superclass in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop

I am having a little trouble with my code.  I understand the concept of method chaining and constructor chaining but can't get it to work right.  Here is what I have so far:

```javascript
function Set() {
    this.values = [];
}

Set.prototype.add = function() {
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        this.values.push(arguments[i]);
    }
}

var regSet = new Set();
regSet.add(10, 11, null);
console.log(regSet.values);  // → [10, 11, null];

function NonNullSet() {
    Set.apply(this, arguments);
}

NonNullSet.prototype = Object.create(Set.prototype);
NonNullSet.prototype.constructor = NonNullSet;

NonNullSet.prototype.add = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (arguments[i] == null || arguments[i] == undefined) {
            throw new Error("Can't add null or undefined");
        }
    }

    return Set.prototype.add.apply(this, arguments);
}

var nonNull = new NonNullSet();
nonNull.add(10, 12, null);
console.log(nonNull.values);  // → undefined
```

As you can see from the code above, nonNullSet is a subclass of Set and I am trying to augment the add method by checking for null or undefined values.  If they exist, just continuing looping.  If they are valid values, call the add method of the Set super class, rather than rewriting it.

To me, this looks right and I am not getting the results I want, so something isn't right.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems:

- `continue` skips to the next loop iteration, but the loop doesn't do anything anyway, so `continue`-ing inside it doesn't change anything. Instead, you should actually call `Set.add` inside your loop, giving it one element at a time — but only if the element is non-`null`.
- `console.log(nonNullSet.values)` should be `console.log(nonNull.values)`: `nonNullSet` is your constructor, `nonNull` is your instance.

Also, not exactly *problems*, but other things you should improve:

- You should capitalize `NonNullSet`.
- Inside `Set.prototype.add`, you should make `i` a local variable, by using the `var` keyword.
- Your variable-names contain `null`, but instead of checking for nullity, you check for falsiness. (`null` is falsy, of course, but so are some other things.) I think this is a bit confusing.

Comment: I fixed these and I am still getting the same problems with this.

Comment: Never mind, it works now.  Check the code above.  Thanks for this.